# Why do I get a blank page when using Python CGI in Tomcat

Tags: python, tomcat, cgi, tomcat6

I just began to learn Python CGI, but I did not make it even to testing the simplest Python CGI program.

I use Tomcat 6.0. I have already deleted the comments in `web.xml` and also added `<Context privileged="true">`. In `web.xml`, I gave the "cgiPathPrefix" the value "cgi-bin", and I added this `cgi-bin` folder in the `webapps/ROOT` directory.

The cgi program is simple; as follows with the name `test.cgi`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print("Content-type: text/html")
print()
print("<title>CGI 101</title>")
print("<h1>A First CGI Example</h1>")
print("<P>Hello, CGI World!</p>")
```

When I go to `http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/test.cgi`, I just get a blank page.

What's wrong with this setup?

Comment: If you look at the blank page source, is there anything in it?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"></HEAD>
<BODY></BODY></HTML>

Comment: This doesn't answer you question, but: cgi is a kind of an old concept. I suggest you use [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) - it's the 'modern way' to run python applications.

Comment: when I examine the logs, I found: INFO: cgi: runCGI (stderr):Execution of C:\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\ROOT\cgi-bin\test.cgi aborted due to compilation errors.
Aug 12, 2011 10:41:21 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: cgi: runCGI (stderr):syntax error at C:\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\ROOT\cgi-bin\test.cgi line 2, near ")

Comment: I use Python3. And I have tried to use print, it's the same.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in a different context. Basically, I think the OP's issue was solved in the comments to the question, by eryksun, with the suggestion:

Is the executable parameter set to an empty string?

Using Tomcat 7.0 I had everything set up so that the server did not produce any errors on startup, and it allowed me to request from the WEB-INF/cgi with a 200 "OK" response, but it gave a blank html page, just like the OP noted.

The solution was to extend the default parameters to the conf/web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>cgi</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.CGIServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>debug</param-name>
      <param-value>0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>cgiPathPrefix</param-name>
      <param-value>WEB-INF/cgi</param-value>
    </init-param>
    **<init-param>
      <param-name>executable</param-name>
      <param-value>c:\myexact\path\to\perl.exe</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>passShellEnvironment </param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>**
<load-on-startup>5</load-on-startup>

</servlet>
```

My additions are bolded (**) above.

Basically the critical info comes from the source suggested by eryksun:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/cgi-howto.html

Answer (score -2):

Your sample code is not proper HTML. You need at least

```
 <html>,<head> and <body>
```

tags.

If adding those does not heal the problem then it is a problem with your server configuration and probably the question is more suitable to serverfault.com how to debug what's wrong with your Tomcat.

Comment: I add the tags. Still doesn't work. The log said:Aug 12, 2011 10:51:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: cgi: runCGI (stderr):syntax error at C:\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\ROOT\cgi-bin\test.cgi line 2, near ")

Comment: If it's Python 2.x then you need to do print "foobar", no ( or )